# How to explain to C# to use inherited property instead of parent?

Tags: c#, class, variables, inheritance

I have inherited property in my children class. But when I am trying to call parent method, it always using it's own (parent) property. How I can explain c# to use inherited property?

```
class ParentClass 
{
    protected int autoinc;

    public ParentClass()
    {
        autoinc = 1000;
    }

    public Show()
    {
        Debug.Log("AutoInc = " + autoinc);
    }

}

class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
    protected int autoinc;

    public ChildClass()
    {
        autoinc = 2000;
    }
}

/* Calling code */
ChildClass cc = new ChildClass();
cc.Show();

// I need above code to show 2000, but it shown 1000.
```

Sorry, this is definitely stupid question. But I need your help anyway.

Comment: Neither of these are properties - they're *fields*. They're very different, and it's vital that you understand that difference. Fields can't be virtual - `ParentClass.Show` will *always* use the field declared in `ParentClass`. But why are you trying to declare two fields with different values, rather than setting the value of `autoinc` to 2000 in the `ChildClass` constructor?

Comment: VS should show a warning that you should use the `new` keyword. Whatever you are trying to do, I recommend doing it differently.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, look, I've changed the code to initialize autoinc by 2000 in child class. But anyway it shown 1000.

Comment: @Epsiloncool: No, your code is still declaring a *separate* field in `ChildClass`. Remove that declaration: you only want a single field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`autoinc` field in child class hides declaration of field with same name in parent class. Just remove that field from child class:

```
class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
    public ChildClass()
    {
        autoinc = 2000;
    }
}
```

Remember, when you use inheritance, then Child object **is** Parent object. You don't need to define parent fields or other members in child object, because they all are already here. Unless you want to *hide* or *override* some member of parent class.